# why django haystack spelling_suggestion() is always None

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I need to integrate spell check mechanism in Django application. I found that Haystack has "Spelling Suggestions" method to use it. So I have installed latest dev version(2.0.0 beta) of haysatck with Django(1.4.1).

I have downloaded apache-solr-3.6.0 and configured as like in [doc](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html).

schema.xml

> ./manage.py build_solr_schema > solr-3.6.0/example/solr/conf/schema.xml

myapps/mysearch_index.py

```
from haystack import indexes

class MovieIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True,use_template=True)
    # other field definition
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        prepared_data = super(NoteIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        prepared_data['suggestions'] = prepared_data['text']
        return prepared_data
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="field">suggestions</str>
        <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
        <str name="accuracy">0.7</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
    'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
  },
}
```

Restart the solr search engine

```
cd examples/solr
java -jar start.jar
```

Rebuild the index

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
# 9905 entries indexed
```

Testing through django shell

```
In [1]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
In [2]: len(SearchQuerySet())
Out[3]: 9905
In [4]: sqs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query('spider')
In [5]: suggestion = sqs.spelling_suggestion()
In [6]: print suggestion
None
In [7]:
```

I have gone though several bolgs and forum and tried of lot of settings, But spelling_suggestion is always None.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for reading this post

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable spellcheck for your default request handler in solr config. The step is mentioned in the haystack doc also that you mentioned in your question.

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

If this is not done then this should fix it. If you still face problem or this step is also done then I think you should try querying solr directly in browser to check if suggestions are working there as this will ensure that your solr is setup properly.

Please let me know if you still face problem and I'll try it personally.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to add the lines and restarted the solr, but no effect, still the suggestion is None

Comment: did you get chance to look in to it?

Comment: i am gonna try it myself today, meanwhile can you try hitting solr directly using browser instead of code to eliminate any problems in code

Comment: try running spellcheck directly on solr using http://localhost:8983/solr/spell/?q=spidar

Comment: it is not working for me. You can check below
http://ec2-54-242-117-208.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8983/solr/spell/?q=spidar

can you please post all your config and related files in GIST ?

Comment: try changing your suggestions field to CharField and then rebuild schema and rebuild index.

Comment: I tried, But not changes. Can you please post all the file is gist for reference?

Comment: I have the same problem, i think its somehow related to the suggestions field being a FacetCharField. When i change the field which is used to provide spelling suggestions to another one, (say for example title or name, which are simple CharFields) i'm succesfully obtaining suggestions. What i did was change the `<str name="field">suggestions</str>`to `<str name="field">title</str>`

Comment: I have the same problem, i think its somehow related to the suggestions field being a FacetCharField. When i change the field which is used to provide spelling suggestions to another one, (say for example title or name, which are simple CharFields) i'm succesfully obtaining suggestions. What i did was change the `<str name="field">suggestions</str>`to `<str name="field">title</str>`